# how to remove an object from list using object field

Tags: java, list

I have a List of a person object. Now I want to remove an object and all I know is the instance variables of the object.

I mean I don't have the object, all I can do is create another object with same field values.

Obviously the new object can't be used to remove the original, since both are different.

A very silly question indeed.

Comment: Well, there is much to add here ... please consider improving or deleting your input.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the objects in the collection and compare their values to your known values, once you find an object with the same value, remove it and break the loop.

Something like:

```
String knownName = "Joe";
for(Person person : personsCollection)
    if(person.getName().equals(knownName)){
        personsCollection.remove(person);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this will be to implement equals method in Person Class, So when you remove the new object and that equals the old object, the Old object will be removed from the list. You can implement the equals method based on the fields that define equality in your application, it could be some id or name.

eg:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Person) {
        return name.equals((Perrson)obj).name();
    }
    return false;
}
```